# I don't get the specified page interval while running Spring Data Jpa Pagination

Tags: java, pagination, spring-data-jpa

- entity

```java
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES_VIEW")
@Entity
public class EmployeeView {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEEID")
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "SALARY")
    private Double salary;
```

- repository

```java
public interface EmployeeViewPaginationRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<EmployeeView, Long> {
    List<EmployeeView> findAllBySalary(Double Salary, Pageable pageable);

}
```

- service

```java
    /**
     *
     * @param salary value of field that is done an query
     * @param numberPage start number of the page to get the requested list from
     * @param amountPage the number of pages received per request
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Iterable<EmployeeViewDto> getAllBySalary(Double salary, Integer numberPage, Integer amountPage) {

        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(numberPage, amountPage);

        Iterable<EmployeeView> employeeViews = findEmployeesFromViewPagination(salary, pageRequest);

        Iterable<EmployeeViewDto> listDto = transformViewPagToListDto(employeeViews);

        return listDto;
    }


    private Iterable<EmployeeView> findEmployeesFromViewPagination(Double salary, Pageable pageable){

        Iterable<EmployeeView> allEmployees = this.paginationRepository.findAllBySalary(salary, pageable);

        return allEmployees;
    }
```

I pass these parameters for pagination:

- Integer numberPage = 0;
- Integer amountPage = 5;

I get the result.

I pass these parameters for pagination:

- Integer numberPage = 1;
- Integer amountPage = 5;

I get 0 entries.

I tried that.

```sql
select
        *
    from
        ( select
            row_.*,
            rownum rownum_
        from
            ( select
                employeevi0_.employeeid as employeeid1_5_,
                employeevi0_.address as address2_5_,
                employeevi0_.first_name as first_name3_5_,
                employeevi0_.last_name as last_name4_5_,
                employeevi0_.salary as salary5_5_
            from
                employees_view employeevi0_
            where
                employeevi0_.salary=800.00 ) row_
        where
            rownum <= 10
        )
    where
        rownum_ > 2;
```

I have table with 10 entries.

Who has any idea why this is happening?

**Solution.**

I understood.

When we specify the total number of pages to navigate, we count the specified number from the initial value.

**For example.**

0, 4-we will get pages from 1st to 4th.

1, 4 - we will get pages from 5 to 9.

That is, if we have 10 pages, in this case we will see 3 pages.

So the first parametr is the page number...

```java
 Iterable<EmployeeViewDto> getAllBySalaryFromRefCursor(Integer numberPage, Integer amountPage);
```

Comment: First obvious assumption, do you have more than 5 entries in that table, and with the given salary?

Comment: I think, you can pass page and size parameters like ?page=0&size=5

Comment: There is 5 entries c given salary. The request looks at records with a salary of 800.00 and they are located .

Comment: And I want to check how I get pages from a certain range. For example, from 1 to 3 or from 3 to 5.